# Is Eigen NEON backend optimized to take advantage of the 2x128b NEON execution units which exist starting from ARM A76?

Tags: arm, eigen, simd, neon

Going over Eigen documentation, its not clear whether it was updated since the release of A76 CPU core to take advantage of the wider SIMD it contains (2x128b vs. previous 128b)
I am hoping someone from the development team (or an expert user) can help clarifying that.

Comment: I don’t know answer to that (only used Eigen for AMD64), but I think I know how to find out. AFAIK Eigen doesn’t use assembly. This means the only way they emit manually-vectorized code is intrinsics. In NEON docs on arm.com, find multiplication or FMA intrinsics that handles 256 bit long vectors, then “find in files” within Eigen’s folder, searching for that intrinsic. NEON developers don’t use the term “FMA”, it’s called MLA for multiply+accumulate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Eigen in particular, but in general, one doesn't need to do much to SIMD code to take advantage of different amounts of hardware execution units - especially when the CPUs support out of order execution, they will pick up more instructions that can be executed in parallel when there's more execution units.

If compiling e.g. SIMD intrinsics with a compiler, the compiler may be able to tune the exact scheduling of code if told to optimize specifically for that core (and if the compiler knows the scheduling characteristics for the core). Same thing for handwritten assembly code - it can be tuned and tweaked a bit for different cores' characteristics, but in most cases, it doesn't change very dramatically; more capable cores will execute it faster.

(The factor that primarily affects the bigger picture of how the code is written, which would require a proper rewrite to take advantage of, is usually the number of registers available in the instruction set - but that doesn't change with a hardware implementation with more execution units.)

Comment: That's generally true, although sometimes you might need a completely different strategy with better computational intensity to actually take advantage of wider cores.  (e.g. an algorithm that normally does only 1 FMA per load and store will just bottleneck on load/store execution unit throughput, even if there are 2 FMA units, if there aren't also more load and store units.)  However, I'd hope Eigen has better computational intensity than that when possible because most x86-64 CPUs these days have 2 FMA, 2 load, and 1 store execution units.